# Manage Properties Issue SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, display-template

I am not able to get default SharePoint column in search display template. I have mapping to default column crawl property with custom manage property.

How can i resolve this column in search result?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the column's Managed property is querable so you can search using 
ColumnName:value

[Check This](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/search/manage-the-search-schema?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that a FULL crawl has been run after you map the managed property.  A full crawl is a requirement for the property to work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2013 Search: Missing Managed Property Value for your reference:

https://blogs.perficient.com/2016/02/29/sharepoint-2013-search-missing-managed-property-value/